# How to print Fastreport directly without showing Print Dialog

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I use Fastreport 4. I need to print directly to the printer without showing Print Dialog. I've unchecked the ShowDialog in the Print Options, but it keep showing a print dialog. Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 17):

You should set it after loading report.

```
Report.LoadFromFile('filename');
Report.PrepareReport;
Report.PrintOptions.ShowDialog := False;
Report.Print;
```

Comment: ShowDialog can also be set at designi time on the report itself

Answer (score -1):

If you assign a fake string to "OnRunDialogs" event after loading report below like, your dialogs do not open.

frxMyReport.LoadFromFile(fPath);
frxMyReport.OnRunDialogs ="fakeevent";

Answer (score -1):

```
Report report = new Report();

report.Load(@"C:\Something.frx");

# ... <rest-of-your-code>

report.PrintSettings.ShowDialog = false;

report.Print();
```

Comment: provide a little more context for your answer